# Shadow for rect in svg

Tags: html, svg

I need to make a shadow for `rect` element for `svg`. The  snippet below does the job, but I don't know how to control the **color/opacity** of the **shadow**? Any help will be appreciated!

```
<svg height="120" width="120">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="20" dy="20" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="offOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect width="90" height="90" stroke="green" stroke-width="3" fill="yellow" filter="url(#f1)" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came across this [w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_feoffset.asp) with similar examples. Based on the examples given there, it looks like you need to add few more filters (like `feColorMatrix` and `feGaussianBlur`) to bring the desired effect.

Your code with new filters:

```
<svg height="120" width="120">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="10" dy="10" />
      <feColorMatrix result="matrixOut" in="offOut" type="matrix"
      values="0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="10" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect width="90" height="90" stroke="green" stroke-width="3" fill="yellow" filter="url(#f1)" />
```

You can use this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learningloop/cm09nbjd/1/) also.

**Update:**

We can achieve opacity & color change just with `feColorMatrix` filter. Check this updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learningloop/cm09nbjd/4/).

But, in order achieve the desired color you need to understand more about setting `values` attribute of `feColorMatrix`.

Following links may be helpful:

- [Match colors in feColorMatrix filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977929/match-colors-in-fecolormatrix-filter)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feColorMatrix
- [SVG Drop Shadow - opacity, feOffset and viewBox difficulties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651486/svg-drop-shadow-opacity-feoffset-and-viewbox-difficulties)